# Add form fields to symfony collection type

Tags: symfony

Hello I have been struggling with a problem for some days now.

I have a form type which has a collection type field. I want to add elements to the collection field in the buildform method of my form type.

Here is my code :

```
    $builder  
        ->add('cIName', 'text')
        ->add('cIAttributes', 'collection', array(
            'label' =>false
        ))
    ;

    $builder->get('cIAttributes')->add('cIDescription', 'textarea');
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do ?

Comment: You can follow cookbook on using collection type here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html?

Comment: The thing is that I know exactly the attributes I want to add to my 'cIAttributes' collection field. Is there a means to add them directly in the buildform method. I don't find any such situation in the documentation link @malarzm provided, which I have read and again

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a second form type so you'll have something like this.

```
    //FormType1
    use FormType2


    $builder
        ->add('cIName', 'text')
        ->add('cIAttributes', 'collection', array(
            'label' => false
            'type' => new FormType2()
     ));
```

-

```
    //FormType2
    $builder
         ->add('cIName', 'text')
         ->add('cIDescription', 'textarea');
```